# I'm wondering how the atomicity of writev() is ensured

Tags: linux, kernel

I looked through the Linux kernel code (read_write.c) all the way down to the write() method in any particular file descriptor and see no locks.  For a preemptive kernel, I don't see how atomicity is guaranteed.  Am I missing something?  I suppose the kernel could do some preemption prevention for writev() somewhere else, but that seems like it would be *cheating.*

Comment: IIRC there's an implicit lock somewhere that comes from one of the levels of generic wrapper methods, so when you get down to an actual `write` implementation, it has a lock already taken.

Answer (score 4):

I have a multithreaded Linux x86_64 user program which is writing to an SCTP
socket using the writev() system call.  I wanted to confirm the atomicity of
the writev() system call.

The man page for writev() states:

```
ssize_t writev(int fd, const struct iovec *iov, int iovcnt);

The data transfers performed by readv() and writev() are atomic: the data written by writev()
is written as a single block that is not intermingled with output from writes in other processes
(but see pipe(7) for an exception); analogously, readv() is guaranteed to read a contiguous
block of data from the file, regardless of read operations performed in other threads or processes
that have file descriptors referring to the same open file description (see open(2)).
```

So when I looked at the writev() implementation, I thought I'd clearly see a lock.  When I did not see
the lock in the writev() implementation I started tracing the calls.  Here's what I found.  This is my
first time walking through the Linux kernel source, so please excuse misunderstandings.

The Linux kernel analyzed is 4.4.0 on x86.

writev() implementation starts in fs/read_write.c:896:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(writev, unsigned long, fd, const struct iovec __user *, vec,u nsigned long, vlen)
```

and calls vfs_writev() defined in the same file fs/read_write.c:863

```
ssize_t vfs_writev(struct file *file, const struct iovec __user *vec,
           unsigned long vlen, loff_t *pos)
{
    if (!(file->f_mode & FMODE_WRITE))
        return -EBADF;
    if (!(file->f_mode & FMODE_CAN_WRITE))
        return -EINVAL;

    return do_readv_writev(WRITE, file, vec, vlen, pos);
}
```

where do_readv_writev() is also in fs/read_write.c:798, and for type WRITE will run,

```
fn = (io_fn_t)file->f_op->write;
iter_fn = file->f_op->write_iter;
file_start_write(file);
```

file_start_write() is an inline function in include/linux/fs.h:2512,

```
static inline void file_start_write(struct file *file)
{
    if (!S_ISREG(file_inode(file)->i_mode))
        return;
    __sb_start_write(file_inode(file)->i_sb, SB_FREEZE_WRITE, true);
}
```

S_ISREG() is defined in include/uapi/linux/stat.h:20 to check if descriptor is a regular file.

And __sb_start_write is defined in fs/super.c:1252

```
/*
 * This is an internal function, please use sb_start_{write,pagefault,intwrite}
 * instead.
 */
int __sb_start_write(struct super_block *sb, int level, bool wait)
{
    bool force_trylock = false;
    int ret = 1;

#ifdef CONFIG_LOCKDEP
    /*
     * We want lockdep to tell us about possible deadlocks with freezing
     * but it's it bit tricky to properly instrument it. Getting a freeze
     * protection works as getting a read lock but there are subtle
     * problems. XFS for example gets freeze protection on internal level
     * twice in some cases, which is OK only because we already hold a
     * freeze protection also on higher level. Due to these cases we have
     * to use wait == F (trylock mode) which must not fail.
     */
    if (wait) {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < level - 1; i++)
            if (percpu_rwsem_is_held(sb->s_writers.rw_sem + i)) {
                force_trylock = true;
                break;
            }
    }
#endif
    if (wait && !force_trylock)
        percpu_down_read(sb->s_writers.rw_sem + level-1);
    else
        ret = percpu_down_read_trylock(sb->s_writers.rw_sem + level-1);

    WARN_ON(force_trylock & !ret);
    return ret;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(__sb_start_write);
```

I don't believe my kernel was compiled with CONFIG_LOCKDEP based on this
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892822/how-to-use-lockdep-feature-in-linux-kernel-for-deadlock-detection)

The filesystem locking is described in comments starting in fs/super.c:1322

```
/**
 * freeze_super - lock the filesystem and force it into a consistent state
 * @sb: the super to lock
 *
 * Syncs the super to make sure the filesystem is consistent and calls the fs's
 * freeze_fs.  Subsequent calls to this without first thawing the fs will return
 * -EBUSY.
 *
 * During this function, sb->s_writers.frozen goes through these values:
 *
 * SB_UNFROZEN: File system is normal, all writes progress as usual.
 *
 * SB_FREEZE_WRITE: The file system is in the process of being frozen.  New
 * writes should be blocked, though page faults are still allowed. We wait for
 * all writes to complete and then proceed to the next stage.
 *
 * SB_FREEZE_PAGEFAULT: Freezing continues. Now also page faults are blocked
 * but internal fs threads can still modify the filesystem (although they
 * should not dirty new pages or inodes), writeback can run etc. After waiting
 * for all running page faults we sync the filesystem which will clean all
 * dirty pages and inodes (no new dirty pages or inodes can be created when
 * sync is running).
 *
 * SB_FREEZE_FS: The file system is frozen. Now all internal sources of fs
 * modification are blocked (e.g. XFS preallocation truncation on inode
 * reclaim). This is usually implemented by blocking new transactions for
 * filesystems that have them and need this additional guard. After all
 * internal writers are finished we call ->freeze_fs() to finish filesystem
 * freezing. Then we transition to SB_FREEZE_COMPLETE state. This state is
 * mostly auxiliary for filesystems to verify they do not modify frozen fs.
 *
 * sb->s_writers.frozen is protected by sb->s_umount.
 */
```

And, finally, in kernel/locking/percpu-rwsem.c:70

```
/*
 * Like the normal down_read() this is not recursive, the writer can
 * come after the first percpu_down_read() and create the deadlock.
 *
 * Note: returns with lock_is_held(brw->rw_sem) == T for lockdep,
 * percpu_up_read() does rwsem_release(). This pairs with the usage
 * of ->rw_sem in percpu_down/up_write().
 */
void percpu_down_read(struct percpu_rw_semaphore *brw)
{
    might_sleep();
    rwsem_acquire_read(&brw->rw_sem.dep_map, 0, 0, _RET_IP_);

    if (likely(update_fast_ctr(brw, +1)))
        return;

    /* Avoid rwsem_acquire_read() and rwsem_release() */
    __down_read(&brw->rw_sem);
    atomic_inc(&brw->slow_read_ctr);
    __up_read(&brw->rw_sem);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(percpu_down_read);
```

So, there's the lock.

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Comment: Indeed. Otherwise I can't (easily) know if your answer has it covered or I should step in and take a look at things.

Comment: Sorry, long time user, first time post.  I'll get this cleaned up.  I'll add kernel versions, filenames and code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Lock and atomicity is not related each other. Lock is used to guarantee mutual exclusiveness among threads accessing shared data. Meanwhile, atomicity guarantees an operation is executed in all-or-nothing fashion.

As C6Up1bQ73STi29cA mentioned, atomicity of writev() is guaranteed by preempt_disable(). In fact, mutual exclusiveness of writev() is not guaranteed in VFS layer. Instead, the filesystem (or one of generic_file* functions - if the fs uses generic layer -) needs to handle multiple writev()s writing to the same part of file.

Answer (score 1):

writev() isn't handled any more special than write(), btw.

It does not guarantee atomicity for all types of file.  Look up `PIPE_BUF`.  If you write more than this amount to a pipe, it may be interleaved with other writes.

For regular files, `f_pos` is currently protected by `f_pos_lock`.  Consider this case as atomically reading and updating f_pos, then calling `pwritev()`.

This protection was a relatively recent "fix" - 2014.  Before then, there was a window of time where Linux was in violation of POSIX, "and nobody
[had] ever cared".  It seems that if you rely on this guarantee in a Linux program, you are doing something fairly unusual :).

- https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/2/17/324
- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/9c225f2655e36a470c4f58dbbc99244c5fc7f2d4

It sounds like there might not be any guarantees for sockets in POSIX.  The mailing list discussion sounds to me like Linux might be providing this guarantee for seekable device files as well.  I'm not sure that we get any guarantees for unseekable ones like ttys.

Comment: Here's the POSIX atomicity guarantee for [write](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html): "An attempt to write to a pipe or FIFO has several major characteristics ... writes of {PIPE_BUF} or fewer bytes shall be atomic". As this answer suggests, POSIX does not appear to extend this guarantee to sockets or even to regular files. The only information I can find in POSIX about atomicity of operations on regular files does not indicate that there is any lower bound on how many bytes will be written out atomically.